# QGIS - Provider does not support deletion

Tags: qgis

Trying to delete a set of paths/routes/vertices (what ever they are called) and I don't seem to be able too. I selected the paths with "select features by polygon" tool.

Layer editing is on. The layer is a KML file that was imported as a Vector Layer.

Any suggestions?
[image]

**+++ Solution +++**

Export layer as GeoPackage. Then edit that new layer.

[image]

[image]

QGIS Version: 3.28.1

Comment: Please do not break the Q&A model by posting an Answer in the Question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In QGIS, KML layer supports only '*Add Features, Add Attributes, Feature Symbology*' capabilities. If you want to delete a feature, you have to export kml layer as shapefile, GeoPackage etc.

Comment: Which file type do you recommend? Looking to make deletions and then edits later on and would like a file type that would be able to handle that. Also plan on exporting as a KML / GPX file when finished.

Comment: geopackage for kml features, shapefile fields will truncate

Comment: Got it. GeoPackage it is.

Comment: http://switchfromshapefile.org/#geopackage